# Using React Hooks to filter two sets of input data on the same component

Tags: reactjs, npm, search, filter, react-hooks

I have two inputs and am trying to have them filter out separate data.  I'm using an NPM package for the filter which works great for the first input, as it returns based on any criteria on the card.  I need the second input to return based on tags that are added after the fact.  I feel like this is a simple answer but I'm a bit new so I can't get this to work.  I've tried using context to get the state from any component but either way, I do this I still can't get it to filter.  Any feedback or help would be greatly appreciated - thanks :)

**Main.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import TagProvider from "../context/TagContext";
import { TagContext } from "../context/TagContext";
import Card from "./Card/Card";
import "./Main.scss";
import FilterResults from "react-filter-search";

export default function Main() {
  //using state with hooks
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [valueTwo, setValueTwo] = useContext(TagContext);

  // axios call to get data
  const url = "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students";
  const getData = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${url}`)
      .then((res) => {
        const studentData = res.data.students;
        setStudents(studentData);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(`Error: ${error}`));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  // handleChange function for filter results

  let handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setValue(value);
  };

  let handleChangeTwo = (event) => {
    const { valueTwo } = event.target;
    setValueTwo(valueTwo);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TagProvider>
        <div className="main">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="main__search"
            value={value}
            placeholder="Search by name"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="main__search"
            value={valueTwo}
            placeholder="Search by tag"
            onChange={handleChangeTwo}
          />

          <FilterResults
            value={value}
            data={students}
            renderResults={(results) => (
              <div className="main__container">
                {results.map((item) => (
                  <Card
                    key={item.id}
                    email={item.email}
                    company={item.company}
                    skill={item.skill}
                    firstname={item.firstName}
                    lastname={item.lastName}
                    grades={item.grades}
                    pic={item.pic}
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </TagProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Card.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./Card.scss";
import Tags from "../Tags/Tags";
import TagProvider from "../../context/TagContext";

export default function Card(props) {
  const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
  const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");
  const content = useRef(null);

  function toggleAccordion() {
    setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
    setHeightState(
      setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    );
  }
  // convert string to integer
  let result = props.grades.map((x) => {
    return parseInt(x, 10);
  });

  // caluclate average function
  const average = (nums) => nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / nums.length;

  const gradeTitle = [
    "Test 1:",
    "Test 2:",
    "Test 3:",
    "Test 4:",
    "Test 5:",
    "Test 6:",
    "Test 7:",
    "Test 8:",
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Card Section */}
      <div className="card__container">
        <img className="card__image" src={props.pic} alt="avatar" />
        <div className="card__container-two">
          <div className="card__container-plus">
            <h1 className="card__name">
              {props.firstname} {props.lastname}
            </h1>
            <button className="card__button" onClick={toggleAccordion}>
              &#43;
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="card__container-three">
            <div className="card__info">Email: {props.email}</div>
            <div className="card__info">Company: {props.company}</div>
            <div className="card__info">Skill: {props.skill}</div>
            <div className="card__info">Average: {average(result)}%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <TagProvider>
        <Tags />
      </TagProvider>

      {/* Card Expansion */}
      <div className="accordion">
        <div
          ref={content}
          style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}
          className="accordion__content"
        >
          <div className="accordion__tests">
            <div className="accordion__test-title">
              {gradeTitle.map((title) => (
                <div>{title}</div>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="accordion__test-results">
              {result.map((number) => (
                <li>{number}%</li>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            className="accordion__text"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    // </TagContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**Tags.jsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { X } from "react-feather";
import "./Tags.scss";
import { TagContext } from "../../context/TagContext";
import TagProvider from "../../context/TagContext";

export default function Tags() {
  const [tags, setTags] = useContext(TagContext);

  return (
    <TagProvider>
      <div className="tags">
        <ul className="tags__list">
          {tags.map((tag) => (
            <li className="tags__tag">
              {tag}
              <X
                className="tags__close-icon"
                size="16"
                onClick={() => {
                  setTags([...tags.filter((word) => word !== tag)]);
                }}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>

        <div className="tags__form">
          <input
            className="tags__input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add a tag.."
            onKeyPress={(event) => {
              if (event.key === "Enter") {
                setTags([...tags, event.target.value]);
                event.target.value = "";
              }
            }}
            autofocus
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </TagProvider>
  );
}
```

**TagContext.js**

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const TagContext = createContext();

const TagProvider = (props) => {
  const [valueTwo, setValueTwo] = useState([]);
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  return (
    <TagContext.Provider value={[valueTwo, setValueTwo, tags, setTags]}>
      {props.children}
    </TagContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TagProvider;
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, things are 50% clear from your description?

Comment: Remvove all TagProvider from all *.js files, except for main.js. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you have in `context/TagContext`, but normally, one provider should be used only once, and should be placed wrapping the Childs that will be subscribe to that context, and you are using the `TagProvider` in Main.js, Tag.js and Card.js, you should keep only the `TagProvider` that is in Main.js file.
After removing additional providers, the next change to do is pass through that provider the values, by putting the `value` prop on it: `<TagProvider value={[valueTwo, setValueTwo]}>`. Whit this code we pass an array that in the first position will have the `valueTwo` and in the second position the `setValueTwo` function.
After that, any component that be inside of the provider (no matter the depth level) can subscribe to that context and use the values.
So in Tag.js, when you use this code: `useContext(TagContext);` it will resolve into an array that will have what you pass through the provider value, and that will be an array with the form of: `[valueTwo, setValueTwo]`.

These answer is based on what you should have on `context/TagContext` so it will be nice if you share that code too.

Comment: Updated with TagContext!